# Point all URLs to a single web page with node.js + express + jQuery

Tags: node.js, express

I just started experimenting with node & express, and am trying to load the content of various HTML files into a single web page with Ajax.

I want the URL shown in the address bar to reflect the actual file structure on my server; so for instance when a user clicks a link with `href="posts/thePost.html"`, instead of actually going to that page, I use `click()`, `preventDefault()`, and Ajax to load the content in a div, then `pushState()` and `window.onpopstate` to make the address bar show the relative path of the file. I do not want to use the hash (`#`) symbol or queries (`?=`) or anything like that, I want normal URLs.

This works fine, but when I refresh the page, the file located at the URL (i.e. `posts/thePost.html`) is displayed instead of `index.html` with the loaded content. Is there a way to use node to fix this, maybe by intercepting the request and displaying the content of `index.html` instead? I've tried to search this but haven't been having any luck.

Sorry if this sounds confusing. In short, the behavior that I'm looking for is that **no matter what URL the address bar shows when the page is refreshed, `index.html` should be served up instead**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's rather easy to do:

```
function serveIndex(req, res) {
    return res.sendfile('index.html');
}
app.get('*', serveIndex);
app.head('*', serveIndex);
```

You'll likely want to put this after your other routes so you don't end up clobbering them.

Comment: Thanks for the response. With a little modification that almost works:     `return send` has to be `res.send`. Unfortunately it just prints the string "index.html" instead of displaying the file's actual contents. On the positive side, it does this regardless of the URL in the address bar, so I'm part of the way there...

Comment: @apostl3pol: No, `res.send` is completely different from what I was suggesting. You'll need to `require` `send` somewhere or alternatively use `return require('send')(req, 'index.html').pipe(res);`. You may also have to add a dependency into your `package.json` file (if you have one) or `npm install send`.

Comment: Ahh, okay. Question: from the link you gave, it says "`Send` is Connect's `static()` extracted for generalized use". I take it that it's not equivalent to simply using `express.static`, though. Correct?

Comment: @apostl3pol: Send is what `express.static` uses to send the files. I first looked for a way to make `express.static` serve the same file all the time, but I looked at the code and I don't think it's designed to do that, so I went one level down and used Send which is what `express.static` uses.

Comment: Gotcha. And it's working now. It's behavior seems to be very similar to express' `sendfile()`, which I just discovered. But now my js and css files aren't working. Any tips on this before I go I start hunting for a solution? `Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html`

Comment: @apostl3pol: Oh, wow, I guess I had forgotten about `sendfile`. That's definitely preferable. Anyway, as for that error, I'm guessing you have the route above all your other routes. You'll need it to be at the bottom so it doesn't override all your other routes. (Also, while it wouldn't cause you problems, I typo'ed `app.post` rather than `app.head`. You should probably change that so HEAD requests work decently and POST doesn't yield senseless replies.)

Comment: I'm not using any other routes, and I do have it at the bottom. Sounds like I need to set up routes for my css and javascript directories though. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can use `express.static` to handle CSS/JS files, just make sure you `app.use` it before the catch-all routes.

Comment: Thanks, I've got it working now. I'll be sure to upvote this once I get enough reputation points.

Comment: @apostl3pol: Normally if the answer answered your question best then you'd accept it with the checkmark. Upvoting signifies that it was a good answer (or question, if you upvote a question), but accepting an answer shows that out of the current answers, it's the one that best answered your question. See [this question on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234) for more information about accepting answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
var routes = require('./routes/index'); 
app.use('/',routes); 
app.use('/index',routes);

function serveIndex(req, res) {
 res.redirect('/');
}
app.get('*', serveIndex);
```